# Fault tolerant Solr replication architecture

Tags: solr, fault-tolerance

I am using solr with replication. I have one master that indexes data and two slaves which pulls index from master and responds to the queries.

My question is, how can i create fault tolerant architecture? I mean what should i do when master server crashes?

Using replication repeater is an option but i am looking for a better solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming version 4.0 (still in development) includes a feature [SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) which gives you fault tolerant masters and crash recovery.